# Laravel tanthammar/laravel-window-size - content within breakpoint statements only displays after refreshing

Tags: javascript, laravel, window, breakpoints, viewport

I am using tanthammar/laravel-window-size which does a great job but when I open the page the first time or when I change the window size on a desktop, the content within the correct breakpopint does not show unless I refresh the page.  How can I make sure that refresh is automatic?

You can see it in action [in one of my blog](https://www.paulgodard.com/blog/79?title=Angolan_adventure).

Here is the code.

```
 <head>
 <x-window-size::save-to-session />
 </head>
 <body>
 @windowWidthGreaterThan(768)
 <!-- only visible on md & larger screen - hidden on sm & smaller screens -->
 <div class="article-body d-none d-md-block">
    {!! $article->body !!}
 </div>
 @else
 <!-- only visible on xs & sm screens - hidden on md & wider screens -->
 <div class="article-body d-md-none">
    {!! $article->bodyX !!}
 </div>
 @endif
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using css, the content of the page will update in realtime as the user resizes the window, whereas this package debounces a network request and updates the page on the next page request.

It's important to understand the difference between the server side rendered breakpoints, that this package provides, and css media queries.